# mt_rand math numbers

Tags: php

I want to create an application that shows multiplication, addition, subtraction and division with 2 random numbers. I made a function that shows random numbers:

```
function Numbers() {
    echo(mt_rand() . "<br>");
    echo(mt_rand() . "<br>");
    echo(mt_rand(1,10));

}
  
Numbers();
```

Can someone **explain** to me how I can make it go +/- and x each other?

I now changed my code to this:

```
function Numbers() {
    $Number1= echo(mt_rand() . "<br>");
    $Number2= echo(mt_rand() . "<br>");
   
    $Number1 + $Number2;
    $Number1 - $Number2;
    $Number1 / $Number2;

}
  
Numbers();
```

Comment: You ask how to add one value to another? There's a `+` operator for it: `echo 2 + 3;`

Comment: If you want 2 random numbers, why does your function echo 3?

Comment: Change the function to generate ONE number and return it, otherwise how are you going to do anything with these numbers

Comment: @u_mulder i now change the code? you mean like that?

Comment: pass the required `+-/*` in a parameter (`<input name="action" ....>`) if this is a form and then use a switch to perform the required action. `switch ($actions) { case '+' : ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example for the addition, you figure out the rest:

```php
$a = mt_rand();
$b = mt_rand();
echo "$a + $b = " . ($a + $b);
```

Comment: oohh I get it now, i was completely doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
function printRnd()
{
    $a_ = rand(1,10);
    $b_ = rand(1,10);
    echo "a={$a_}, b={$b_}<br><br>";
    $plus_ = $a_+$b_;
    $minus_ = $a_-$b_;
    $multi_ = $a_*$b_;
    $divid_ = $a_/$b_;
    echo "a+b={$plus_}<br>";
    echo "a-b={$minus_}<br>";
    echo "a*b={$multi_}<br>";
    echo "a/b={$divid_}<br>";
}
printRnd();
```